# Tidal Info Retrieve

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, tidal-scheduler

I am a novice and I need your help.

The following is a part of JSON data from NOAA Tidal API. 
`t` stands for time and it contains date and time.
`v` stands for water level.

```
{
     "predictions" : [

{
            "t":"2014-11-05 00:00",
             "v":"0.183"
        },
        {
            "t":"2014-11-05 00:06",
             "v":"0.202"
        },
```

the data continues for every six minute.

What I want to show are high/low tides (highest `v` and lowest `v`) and the associated time. 
Each high/low tide happens twice a day (twelve hour cycle), 
so I need to retrieve two highest values and two lowest values for each day.

Please someone help me!

Comment: You have a specific language you want to do this in?

Comment: I am trying to code with javascript!

Comment: What have you tried? You can put all the items into an array and sort them. Then just get the first and last elements

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [underscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/#max).

E.g for max value:

```
 _.max(data['predictions'] , 
   function(prediction) { 
       return prediction.v
    });
```